WordPress - How to correctly do custom query on cpt in elementor
I'm trying to use a custom query in my elementor project in combination with a post widget. Since I need to create a custom layout, my idea is to get custom post type using the custom query way of elementor development documentation.
I've added a single post widget in each column of my container, and I've assigned a specific query ID. In my php code I now have added this code to dump the query and see if all is working fine, and I'm able to do a var_dump on the query but I'm unable to understad if the posts are correctly extracted.
this is the var_dump result on the $query variable
object(WP_Query)#3418 (50) { ["query"]=> array(10) { ["posts_per_page"]=> int(1) ["paged"]=> int(1) ["has_custom_pagination"]=> bool(false) ["post_status"]=> string(7) "publish" ["post_type"]=> string(9) "portfolio" ["orderby"]=> string(9) "post_date" ["order"]=> string(4) "desc" ["ignore_sticky_posts"]=> bool(false) ["post__not_in"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(1109) } ["date_query"]=> array(0) { } } ["query_vars"]=> array(61) { ["posts_per_page"]=> int(1) ["paged"]=> int(1) ["has_custom_pagination"]=> bool(false) ["post_status"]=> string(7) "publish" ["post_type"]=> string(9) "portfolio" ["orderby"]=> string(9) "post_date" ["order"]=> string(4) "desc" ["ignore_sticky_posts"]=> bool(false) ["post__not_in"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(1109) } ["date_query"]=> array(0) { } ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["m"]=> string(0) "" ["p"]=> int(0) ["post_parent"]=> string(0) "" ["subpost"]=> string(0) "" ["subpost_id"]=> string(0) "" ["attachment"]=> string(0) "" ["attachment_id"]=> int(0) ["name"]=> string(0) "" ["pagename"]=> string(0) "" ["page_id"]=> int(0) ["second"]=> string(0) "" ["minute"]=> string(0) "" ["hour"]=> string(0) "" ["day"]=> int(0) ["monthnum"]=> int(0) ["year"]=> int(0) ["w"]=> int(0) ["category_name"]=> string(0) "" ["tag"]=> string(0) "" ["cat"]=> string(0) "" ["tag_id"]=> string(0) "" ["author"]=> string(0) "" ["author_name"]=> string(0) "" ["feed"]=> string(0) "" ["tb"]=> string(0) "" ["meta_key"]=> string(0) "" ["meta_value"]=> string(0) "" ["preview"]=> string(0) "" ["s"]=> string(0) "" ["sentence"]=> string(0) "" ["title"]=> string(0) "" ["fields"]=> string(0) "" ["menu_order"]=> string(0) "" ["embed"]=> string(0) "" ["category__in"]=> array(0) { } ["category__not_in"]=> array(0) { } ["category__and"]=> array(0) { } ["post__in"]=> array(0) { } ["post_name__in"]=> array(0) { } ["tag__in"]=> array(0) { } ["tag__not_in"]=> array(0) { } ["tag__and"]=> array(0) { } ["tag_slug__in"]=> array(0) { } ["tag_slug__and"]=> array(0) { } ["post_parent__in"]=> array(0) { } ["post_parent__not_in"]=> array(0) { } ["author__in"]=> array(0) { } ["author__not_in"]=> array(0) { } ["search_columns"]=> array(0) { } ["post_title"]=> string(6) "test 6" } ["tax_query"]=> object(WP_Tax_Query)#3417 (6) { ["queries"]=> array(0) { } ["relation"]=> string(3) "AND" ["table_aliases":protected]=> array(0) { } ["queried_terms"]=> array(0) { } ["primary_table"]=> NULL ["primary_id_column"]=> NULL } ["meta_query"]=> bool(false) ["date_query"]=> bool(false) ["post_count"]=> int(0) ["current_post"]=> int(-1) ["before_loop"]=> bool(true) ["in_the_loop"]=> bool(false) ["comment_count"]=> int(0) ["current_comment"]=> int(-1) ["found_posts"]=> int(0) ["max_num_pages"]=> int(0) ["max_num_comment_pages"]=> int(0) ["is_single"]=> bool(false) ["is_preview"]=> bool(false) ["is_page"]=> bool(false) ["is_archive"]=> bool(true) ["is_date"]=> bool(false) ["is_year"]=> bool(false) ["is_month"]=> bool(false) ["is_day"]=> bool(false) ["is_time"]=> bool(false) ["is_author"]=> bool(false) ["is_category"]=> bool(false) ["is_tag"]=> bool(false) ["is_tax"]=> bool(false) ["is_search"]=> bool(false) ["is_feed"]=> bool(false) ["is_comment_feed"]=> bool(false) ["is_trackback"]=> bool(false) ["is_home"]=> bool(false) ["is_privacy_policy"]=> bool(false) ["is_404"]=> bool(false) ["is_embed"]=> bool(false) ["is_paged"]=> bool(false) ["is_admin"]=> bool(false) ["is_attachment"]=> bool(false) ["is_singular"]=> bool(false) ["is_robots"]=> bool(false) ["is_favicon"]=> bool(false) ["is_posts_page"]=> bool(false) ["is_post_type_archive"]=> bool(true) ["query_vars_hash":"WP_Query":private]=> string(32) "dde53a81e3d1ee97516abbcf05188915" ["query_vars_changed":"WP_Query":private]=> bool(false) ["thumbnails_cached"]=> bool(false) ["allow_query_attachment_by_filename":protected]=> bool(false) ["stopwords":"WP_Query":private]=> NULL ["compat_fields":"WP_Query":private]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(15) "query_vars_hash" [1]=> string(18) "query_vars_changed" } ["compat_methods":"WP_Query":private]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(16) "init_query_flags" [1]=> string(15) "parse_tax_query" } }

This is the PHP code
add_action('elementor/query/top_left_portfolio_column', function( $query ){
    $query->set('post_type', 'portfolio');
    //$query->set('posts_per_page', 3);
    var_dump( $query );
});

From the dump I can see that the custom query is executed, but I'm not able to get posts details.
How I will get only the post links, titles and featured images of my custom post type with the query? I can also have a custom pagination that will update the displayed posts when a button is clicked (also button can be used to do custom actions in elementor)?


Install the plugin CPT UI, it will simplify things for you by a lot and add a multitude of extra customization options, the way you're adding a custom query right now is a bit messy, if still proceed by adding a custom post type / query with php then you will have to create custom fields for the 'portfolio' post type (post content, featured image, ect.) by creating a new post type you have completely separated it from WP Post (core) and the editing fields that comes with it.
In my opinion Utilizing CPT UI is your best bet.

And this would answer the question how?

It answers why the post content isn't pulling through and what needs to be done to get it to pull through which was part of the question. I won't be able to solve the coding dynamics, but I thought the additional information would be helpful with the added suggestion of using CPT UI.

"it answers why the post content isn't pulling through" - Where? All I can see is a lot of text, which is redundant and doesn't add anything to the answer.

I see, my answers should be more concise and instead of answering part of the question I should only post an answer if I have the full solution. This is only my second day here. Thank you for your guidance.

Well just mentioning the library doesn't make this a good answer. It would be better if you actually provided on how to use the library and how it would be a good fit to solve the issue OP is experiencing

Hi, welcome. Please read how to answer
